# copy jupyter lab notebooks from github

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, cicd, jupyterhub

We have jupyter lab installed on kubernetes and notebooks uploaded to github. I want to copy these  notebooks to another instance of jupyter lab. So, I logged into the pod and ran git clone command. notebooks were copied and they are visible in UI too. But other users are unable to see these files as we have user specific pods. Can someone please suggest how to make these notebooks available to other users in read only mode.

Comment: Can you just give them read only access to the git repo?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I understand we can grant access to repo. But user wants to login and verify the code.

Comment: there's no way to automatically share a device across nodes within kubernetes-based jupyterhub deployments that I'm aware of, and a quick search online confirms that as far as I can tell. there is lots of discussion on jupyterhub forums asking for this, but the implementation is quite complex and setup specific. the best option as far as I can see would be to mount a filesystem-style cloud storage service. but configuring read-only access for some users and not others will be a real challenge. best thing we've found is push to git and others pull.